# Can local WordPress installs share /wp-content/ folder and database?

Tags: database, content, customization, local-installation

On my local machine, I have multiple wordpress versions installed so I can test the themes and plugins I develop.

I was wondering if I could somehow create a central wp-content folder and database, which are linked to each version of wordpress, so I don't have to continually copy my projects between the them?

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29273/share-media-among-different-domains

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/175143/sharing-the-wp-content-folder-over-different-wordpress-multisite-installs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `wp-content` folder you need to add WP_CONTENT_DIR with path to this folder to each `wp-config.php` file of each your sites. All of these WP_CONTENT_DIR constants should have the same path to one folder. Read more about it here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Moving_wp-content

To share the same database, you just need to setup the same database settings in each `wp-config.php` files. Read about it here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Set_Database_Name

**UPDATE:** To make your urls work correctly define `WP_SITEURL` and `WP_HOME` constants which will override options settings. Read about it here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#WordPress_address_.28URL.29

Comment: Thank you, this works great. The only problem is, the database contains two values in the wp_options table: 'siteurl' and 'home' that contain the url to only one of my installs, which messes with the links on the front end and won't allow me to enter the wp-admin of my other installs. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: @Sarathi I have updated my answer, use `WP_SITEURL` and `WP_HOME` constants for it.

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you for all of your help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a WordPress Multisite Network setup? Have you considered WordPress (Multisite) Network setup? Take a look at this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

> A multisite network is a collection of sites that all share the same
> WordPress installation. They can also share plugins and themes.
>
> The individual sites in the network are virtual sites in the sense that
> they do not have their own directories on your server, although they
> do have separate directories for media uploads within the shared
> installation, and they do have separate tables in the database.

Comment: I have looked into a WordPress Multisite, but that seems to allow one WordPress install to run multiple sites, rather than multiple WordPress installs having a central data storage.

Comment: @Sarathi looks like I misunderstood your question. Glad you got an answer. :)

Comment: That's fine, I'm not always great at explaining myself. But thanks for your response. :)