# What should I use instead of WP_CONTENT_DIR and WP_PLUGIN_DIR?

Tags: plugin-development, constants

The WordPress documentation for [Determining Plugin and Content Directories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories) states that:

> WordPress makes use of the following constants when determining the
>   path to the content and plugin directories. **These should not be used
>   directly by plugins or themes**, but are listed here for completeness.

It goes on to list `WP_CONTENT_DIR` and `WP_PLUGIN_DIR` among constants that theme and plugin developers should not use, presumably because of this:

> WordPress allows users to place their wp-content directory anywhere
>   they want, so you must never assume that plugins will be in
>   wp-content/plugins, or that uploads will be in wp-content/uploads, or
>   that themes will be in wp-content/themes.

Mark Jaquith also [comments here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3128891/88487) that those constants should not be used:

> Don't use WP_PLUGIN_URL or WP_PLUGIN_DIR — plugins might not be in the
>   plugins directory.

**So, what is the accepted way of referencing the full path to the plugins, wp-content, and themes folders without using these constants?**

As a simple example, to output the full path of all installed plugins, I can do this:

```
<?php
$plugins = get_plugins();

foreach ($plugins as $file => $details) {
    echo WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/' . $file . '<br>';
}
```

Which produces a list like so:

```
/var/www/wp-content/plugins/akismet/akismet.php
/var/www/wp-content/plugins/debug-bar/debug-bar.php
/var/www/wp-content/plugins/hello.php
```

(I might want to do this if I was writing a plugin to allow the user to selectively archive plugins as part of a site backup, for example.)

If using `WP_PLUGIN_DIR` is wrong, what is the suggested alternative? There is no equivalent to [`wp_upload_dir()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_dir) for the plugins, themes, and wp-content folder that I can find, which makes referencing the potentially wandering themes and plugins root directories problematic.

Comment: Take a look at the Codex article [Determining Plugin and Content Directories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories).

Comment: @CharlesClarkson I reference that page in the first sentence of my question. It says not to use the above constants, but doesn't suggest an alternative to things like `WP_PLUGIN_DIR`, hence my question here.

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/54063/have-multiple-local-wordpress-installs-share-a-wp-content-folder-and-database

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Reference file in current path or deeper nested

To reference the current path

```
plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )."further/nesting/here.css";
```

which works in **Plugins and Themes**.

### Reference URl/URi in a plugin

To point to a plugin or theme file, use

```
plugins_url( "path/to/file", __FILE__ );
```

which works only in plugins

### Reference URl/URi in `wp-admin` folder

Always point them to `admin_url( 'some/path' );`. There is `get_admin_url()` as well.

### Reference URl/Uri in `wp-includes` folder

Point them to [`includes_url( 'some/path' );`](http://queryposts.com/function/includes_url/)

### An URl/URi relative to the sites home

There's [`home_url( 'etc' );`](http://queryposts.com/function/home_url/) or `get_home_url()` for that. Similar is [`get_site_url()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_site_url/) and `site_url()`. Then there as well is [`network_home_url()`](http://queryposts.com/function/network_home_url/). And you got [`network_admin_url()`](http://queryposts.com/function/network_admin_url/)

### `wp-content` or the renamed directory

You can redefine the `wp-content` folder name. Therefore you use [`content_url()`](http://queryposts.com/function/content_url/) there.

### How to get the plugins folder url?

> If using WP_PLUGIN_DIR is wrong, what is the suggested alternative?

Simply use `plugins_url()` without any parameters.

If you use it for a plugin, it works for MU plugins too.

**EDIT #1** If you're interested in the path to the current plugin, use `plugin_basename();`.

**EDIT #2** If you're interested in all sidewide active plugins, use `wp_get_active_network_plugins();`.

If you're not on multisite, go with [`wp_get_active_and_valid_plugins();`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_get_active_and_valid_plugins/). This will take multisite/network into account. Keep in mind that this will take them into account if you're not on multisite, but got a `sunrise.php` dropin.

You *could* as well retrieve them via `get_option( 'active_plugins' );`, which is **not recommended** as it doesn't take filters and plugin validation into account, which happens on several occasions.

---

### Further reading

This list goes on and on. Take a look at the search results on [QueryPosts.com](http://queryposts.com/?s=_url) for more info.

[This **article**](http://wpkrauts.com/2015/the-guide-to-wordpress-path-and-urls/) goes in **absolute depth** about all paths.

Comment: Thanks for this, but your answer seems to deal with URLs rather than absolute server paths, which is what I was interested in. For example, `plugins_url()` returns the URL to the plugins folder, not the full path to the directory on the server. Are there similar functions for handling directories that I'm not aware of? Or is the advice not to use the `WP_PLUGIN_DIR` constant simply wrong?

Comment: (I'm specifically interested in finding the full path to installed plugins other than the plugin that contains my own code, in case that helps to explain.)

Comment: @Nick See update.

Comment: The article that "goes in absolute depth about all plugins" is no longer available. And I still cannot understand how to get the absolute path to the plugins directory without using `WP_PLUGIN_DIR`.

Answer (score 4):

1. This returns the current plugin's directory's server path:

   ```
   plugin_dir_path(__FILE__)

   // example: /home/myserver/public_html/wordpress_install/wp-content/plugins/exampleplugin/
   ```

   Ref: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_dir_path

   Not to be confused with:

   ```
   plugins_dir_path(__FILE__)
   ```

   (Notice the plural "plugin**s**" on that.)
2. Since you don't want the plugin directory name returned we have to strip that out. Here's a function which returns the plugin directory and file name:

   ```
   plugin_basename(__FILE__)

   // example: exampleplugin/exampleplugin.php
   ```
3. But of course we don't want the plugin's filename either, so we'll need to strip that out of `plugin_basename(__FILE__)` first. To return the plugin's file name:

   ```
   basename(__FILE__)

   // example: exampleplugin.php
   ```
4. So to use these to construct a path to the *plugins* directory, we can use the `str_replace()` function something like this:

   ```
   $myBnm = basename(__FILE__); // value: exampleplugin.php
   $myDir = plugin_basename(__FILE__); // value: exampleplugin/exampleplugin.php
   $myStr = str_replace($myBnm,"",$myDir); // value: exampleplugin/
   $myPth = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__); // value: /home/myserver/public_html/wordpress_install/wp-content/plugins/exampleplugin/
   return str_replace($myStr,"",$myPth); // returns: /home/myserver/public_html/wordpress_install/wp-content/plugins/
   ```
5. And if needed, that final line can of course be assigned to a variable, for repeat use.

   Instead of:

   ```
   return str_replace($myStr,"",$myPth); // returns: /home/myserver/public_html/wordpress_install/wp-content/plugins/
   ```

   Use something like:

   ```
   $thePlgDir = str_replace($myStr,"",$myPth); // returns: /home/myserver/public_html/wordpress_install/wp-content/plugins/
   ```

   And later, when needed:

   ```
   return $thePlgDir;
   ```