# How can the plugin directory path be returned into <script> </script>?

Tags: php, pages, javascript

How can the plugin directory path be returned into `<script> </script>` instead of hard coding the path?

Here is the custom-page.php:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://local.wordpress.test/wp-content/plugins/path-to-file/script.js"></script>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Is your question about the script (_javascript.js_)? Then use [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/). Is it about using the path as a variable within JavaScript? Then [`wp_localize_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/) is your friend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/119084/121955

```
plugins_url( "path/to/file", __FILE__ );
```

EDITED:

```
<script src="<?php echo plugins_url( "path/to/file", __FILE__ ); ?>"></script>
```

Comment: How would this be applied within the <script> </script> tags?

Comment: Added an example

Answer (score 2):

To make the plugin url available in javascript:

```
/**
  *register the javascript
  */
  wp_register_script( 'some_handle', plugins_url( "plugin-name/path-to-file/script.js") );

  /**
  *localize the plugin url.
  *someObjectName.pluginsUrl then can be used to return
  *the plugin url to the javascript
  */
  wp_localize_script('some_handle', 'someObjectName', array(
      'pluginsUrl' => plugins_url( "plugin-name/path-to-file/script.js"),
  ));
```

From Javascript the plugin url can be returned in the following way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var url = someObjectName.pluginsUrl;
     alert( url );
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from one of my plugins I developed.

```
    function insert_scripts()
{
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery', '<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>', '1.0.0', true);

    wp_enqueue_script( 'test1', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/test1.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'test2', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/test2.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'xwp_insert_scripts' );
```

As per the code above, the scripts should load into the head. However, if modification have been made they could load else where. This funtion will need to be added to a functions.php file. NOTE: if you add this to the core theme functions.php file it will be modified upon update. Best bet is to create a child theme and use a custom functions.php file.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo plugins_url( "plugin-name/path-to-file/script.js"); ?>"></script>
```