# How to share /uploads/ directory with another site on the same server?

Tags: uploads, directory

both main and second domain (addon domain ) are in same host
i want to find a way to change upload directory to another directory that located in another domain root.

**default location (first location) :** My main domain upload directory is : /domains/domain1.com/public_html/wp-content/uploads

**destination location (second location) :** the destination directory. is : /domains/domain2.com/public_html/wp-content/uploads

I want to define second domain upload directory as main domain upload dir

I mean I want domain1.com upload directory uses from the second domain upload directory.

for example can i use another wordpress root location address from same host in this code in wp-config.php ?

```
 wp config function: define('UPLOADS', 'destination directory');
```

if its matter i use shared hosting and my control panel is directadmin

is this possible ?

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29273/share-media-among-different-domains

Comment: It depends on if your shared hosting company allows symlink creation, I'm guessing that some do not. But you can easily add symlinks if you use a cloud server, which are often cheaper anyways... see my answer below.

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/273565/can-multiple-sites-under-one-folder-structure-share-media-directories

Comment: @JesseNickles that is not related, sharing an uploads folder does not share the media library, and you can share the media library without sharing an uploads folder

Answer (score 1):

Well, what you want to achieve saving uploads in another domain? You want to share the uploads folder with another domain?

Did you know you can use more than one domain (site) in a single WordPress Installation? It's called Multisite:
https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/ultimate-guide-multisite/

To change the upload dir. Just use the filter **upload_dir**. It's documented here:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/upload_dir

Be happy!

Comment: Exactly i want to share just upload folder between two  websites for edd products. but in multisite there is some limit for manage, thank you a lot for your help i will test this ,

Comment: can you help me how can i set this location as default location : /home2/username/domains/domain2.com/public_html/wp-content/uploads - I don't  know how to use this filter. - if you can't its ok i try to find a way to use this and And I'm very grateful to you for your time.

Comment: First of all, changing uploads folder will only change where wordpress will save your uploads. How you would get the uploads in media library of wordpress to attach in some of your products? I think you could think in a solution to share the media of the sites. Like if i upload a media in my site, will appear in other site too, like a sync feature. Let's look if have some plugin to solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, What I want is have access the files that I upload on one of the sites from another site too in media library, exactly as you said.

Comment: There is no php function to load another root of same host ? For example :$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']  will be load current files directory , if in this : define('UPLOADS', 'destination directory'); we can put another domains files location (/domains/domain2.com/public_html/wp-content/uploads) - so the problem will be sloved but it seems there is no way for this . Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @PositiveMind, try this, never tested: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpsitesynccontent/. The idea you want is this. Please, test before use.

Comment: As I said to you, sharing the uploads folder like you want will not solve your problem. The only way is using multisite. If you can't use multisite. You have to keep the two sites in two wordpress instances and find a way to sync both sites. The multisite alternative is this: https://github.com/humanmade/network-media-library

Comment: Thankyou but both plugin doesn't work properly , second is for multisite , if i setup multisite can i set special diffrent domain for each of two sites ? i mean not this type of addresses : address.site.com or site.com/address -  and thank you so much for every thing...

Comment: @PositiveMind, sorry about that. Yes, multisite can have multiple domains: https://www.brianshim.com/webtricks/wordpress-multisite-separate-domain-names/. What's your limitation using multisite?

Comment: Thank you , multisite have limite on directly manage themes and plugins , and for special domains name for each site it seems need to have dedicated ip.

Comment: I will test this , i think this is the best way for what i want - another option is using a sync plugin for media library that for now i can't find a good one but i try , thank you so much , it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible with Linux symlinks! [We do this now](https://github.com/littlebizzy/slickstack/blob/master/bash/ss-perms-wordpress-core.txt) on SlickStack staging sites.

There is no way to do it using WordPress configuration settings alone -- WordPress is rather finicky with the `/uploads/` folder in particular, because the defined path must be relative to `/wp-content/` so hacking settings will not work, unless you want to share the [entire directory tree](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/54063/can-local-wordpress-installs-share-wp-content-folder-and-database) which is usually not what questions like yours are looking for.

But you can easily "trick" WordPress into sharing a single folder with symlinks.

In your case, point symlink like this:

```
sudo ln -s -f /domains/domain1.com/public_html/wp-content/uploads /domains/domain2.com/public_html/wp-content/uploads
```

Remember, for symlinks the first directory is "canonical" or the physical source, and the second directory is the actual symlink (virtual directory).

You might also want to setup a cron job to ensure the symlink doesn't get overwritten.

Comment: @TomJNowell Why are you censoring my posts? Self-promotion is verbosely allowed in the rules when relevant and helpful as a coding example. Please stop stalking me all over WPSE, thanks. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/promotion

Comment: You did not disclose your affiliation, nor did it help the answer or explain how it helped, and reposted it on multiple questions. If you find duplicates you should vote to close them as duplicates rather than reposting answers, or flag them if you haven't earnt enough rep to do that yet. As for why I'm looking into it, I'm a community moderator here. If you want to discuss or dispute the links, ask for advice, or ask if your specific case should be allowed then you should post on the meta stack, that's where discussion about the site itself should go.