# Creating an endpoint in wordpress

Tags: endpoints

I'm writing a plugin that will allow some of my installs to talk to each other and share specific information. I wish to specify an endpoint such that `example.com/path/here` is where the other site can GET some nicely formed XML or POST some nicely formed XML (depending on which way the data is flowing).

As a rough hack, I set up `./wp-content/plugins/myplugin/endpoint.php` but I get the impression that direct calling is going to be bad. How do I do this the WordPress way?

Comment: How about creating a [custom REST API endpoint](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/)?

Comment: That might work. How do I do that?

Comment: It's all explained in Sally's link.

Comment: I must be blind. I did not see that.

Comment: After looking at that, it seems REST API only speaks JSON. Looks like I have to give up on my love of XML...

Comment: @MatthewBrownakaLordMatt You can send the data as XML in JSON... `{"myXml":"xml data here"}` ... if it's not easier to just convert the data to JSON..

Comment: I'm coming round to JSON. Conversion is not so hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom endpoint using the [`add_feed`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_feed/) function. I have used this in the past to create custom iCal feeds.

```
// Initialize the feed
function your_add_custom_feed() {
    // This adds a feed http://example.com/?feed=myfeed
    add_feed('myfeed', 'your_create_feed');
}
add_action('init','your_add_custom_feed');

// Create a function to form the output
function your_create_feed() {

    // Query variables are accessible here ($_GET)
    $myvar = get_query_var('myvar');

    // You may need to specify the header before output here depending on your type of feed
    // header(...)

    // Echo your feed here.

}
```

Comment: While my use case has changed due to comments, this is exactly the answer to my question as asked. Which is why I have accepted it. I hope it helps others but I would also point the same others to the comments about JSON.